# Pegar o link de download do firebase storage e salvar numa string do database pra ser exibido no cardview via Picasso ou similar

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-database

Boa noite pessoal. To fazendo um trabalho que preciso pegar a URL de download da imagem que enviei pro storage, salvar essa URL no banco de dados pra conseguir exibir essa imagem na cardview utilizando a library Picasso. Eu consigo enviar a imagem pro storage, as informações pro banco de dados, mas preciso desse link. O getDownloadURL devolver uma URL que parece que o Picasso não consegue acessar ou nem é link de acesso assim. No storage tem um link que se eu colocar ele direto na database, o Picasso mostra normalmente, preciso pegar esse link sempre que inserir uma imagem e salvar na database, assim é só o Picasso acessar essa referencia e mostrar. Essa imagem é enviada pelo ActivityResult, depois vou até dar uma melhorada nisso, mas por enquanto está funcinando, só preciso dessa URL mesmo

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALERIA_IMAGENS) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            imagemURL = mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            imagePath = mStorageRef.child("imagens_livros").child(selectedImage.getLastPathSegment() + ".jpg");
            imagePath.putFile(selectedImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrarLivro.this, "Imagem carregada com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrarLivro.this, "Erro! Não conseguimos enviar a imagem. Tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            imagem.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
```

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424203/firebase-storage-getting-image-url